# Determining if an object with specific value is repeated in a list

Tags: c#

I have a Customer class with First and Last name attributes. Also, I have a list of customers.

```
public static List<Customer> customersList = new List<Customer>();
```

Given a first and last name, what's the cleanest way to find out if this name appears on the list more than once?

Comment: You just need to iterate through your collection and count how many times you meet such first name and last name. If count is more than 1, then it appears more than once :)

Comment: Something along the lines of `.GroupBy(entry => entry.Firstname).ThenBy(entry => entry.Lastname).Where(g => g.Count() > 1)` should be simple enough.

Comment: customersList.GroupBy(x => new {x.FirstName, x.LastName}).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Select(x => new
            {
                x.Key.FirstName,
                x.Key.LastName
            }) oh, Manfred already answered on this "googleable" question

Comment: How is that possible you declare List of Person but new List of Customer

Comment: @RawitasKrungkaew Fixed that. My bad.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define class

```
   public class Customer
    {
        public string FName { get; set; }
        public string LName { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
```

Query here

```
        List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();
        list.Add(new Customer() { FName = "A", LName = "L" });
        list.Add(new Customer() { FName = "A", LName = "L" });
        list.Add(new Customer() { FName = "B", LName = "L" });
        list.Add(new Customer() { FName = "B", LName = "L" });
        list.Add(new Customer() { FName = "C", LName = "L" });

        var isDup = list.Where(x => x.FName.Equals("A") && x.LName.Equals("L")).Count() > 1;
        var isNotDup = list.Where(x => x.FName.Equals("C") && x.LName.Equals("L")).Count() > 1;
```

Result

```
isDup is true
isNotDup is false
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Given FName and LName I want to check if this name is repeated more than once. I just need a boolean value, not a list.

Comment: How is this now?